# Unique function to read different streams

Tags: c, pointers, stream

I'm looking for a way to read **file** and **stdin** stream using a unique **void** function in **C**. I'm trying to use this function:

```
#define ENTER 10 //'\n' ASCII code

........

void read(FILE *stream, char *string) {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    do {
        c = fgetc(stream);
        string = realloc(string, (counter+1) * sizeof(char));
        string[counter++] = c;
    } while(c != ENTER && !feof(stream));

    string[counter-1] = '\0';
}
```

but it's working only with **stdin** stream. When I'm using a text file, the file content isn't visible outside the function. I'm calling this function like:

```
read(stdin, inputString);
read(inputFile, fileContent);
```

and only works right in the **first case**.

P.S.: Initially, inputString an fileContent have been declared as

```
char *inputString = malloc(sizeof(char));
char *fileContent = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and I know **fgetc** returns **int**, the char by char reallocation are expensive (but I need to use only the necessary memory) and EOF or '\n' are stored in string (but are replaced by 0-terminator after).

Comment: You haven't initialized the counter variable.

Comment: Sorry.. Wrote wrongly here, but I've edited now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be working correctly with either because you reallocate the string but don't return the pointer to the new allocation, and because you mishandle `fgetc()`.

You probably need:

```
void read(FILE *stream, char **string)
{
    int c;
    int counter = 0;
    int available = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && c != ENTER)
    {
        if (counter >= available)
        {
            int new_size = (available + 2) * 2;
            void *space = realloc(*string, new_size);
            if (space == 0)
                // Handle out of memory reporting?
                return;
            *string = space;
            available = new_size;
        }
        (*string)[counter++] = c;
    }
    (*string)[counter] = '\0';
}
```

And you'd call it like:

```
read(stdin, &inputString);
read(inputFile, &fileContent);
```

There are many corrections in here; there are still improvements that could and should be made.

1. Pass pointer to pointer so that changes can be reflected in the calling code.  In the original code, you might get away with if the `realloc()` calls can grow the current chunk, but when it has to move memory, the moved location is not available in the calling function.
2. The return type of `fgetc()` is `int`, not `char`.
3. You should prefer `while` loops to `do ... while` loops.  If your code encounters EOF, it tries to put the character value stored into the array.
4. (Still a problem, of sorts) The initial allocation of `string` is largely ignored; it is treated as if it was a zero length allocation.
5. You increment the space stored by one character at a time — which is inefficient.  The revised code approximately doubles the space available each time.  It also allocates enough space for the terminating null byte.
6. Unfixed: the name `read()` is not reserved by standard C, but is effectively reserved if you use any POSIX functions.

You (still) have no way to report an error.  I'd actually prefer a function more like:

```
char *read_line(FILE *stream)
{
    int c;
    int counter = 0;
    int available = 2;
    char *string = malloc(available);

    if (string == 0)
        return string;

    while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && c != ENTER)
    {
        if (counter >= available)
        {
            int new_size = (available + 2) * 2;
            void *space = realloc(string, new_size);
            if (space == 0)
            {
                free(string);
                return 0;
            }
            string = space;
            available = new_size;
        }
        string[counter++] = c;
    }
    string[counter] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

You should also look up the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just return `string` instead of `void` ?

Comment: Yes - I kept more or less the original interface, but it has issues (not least that the initial allocation is immaterial).

Comment: The amount of time you've poured in this answer is truly impressive.

Comment: Yeah - I should probably go and find previous renditions of the answer; I'm tolerably certain it is not the first time I've answered the equivalent question, let alone other people having done so.

Answer (score 0):

Well your function was working fine. Check out the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ENTER 10 //'\n' ASCII code

void read(FILE *stream, char **string) {
char c;
int counter = 0;
do {
    c = fgetc(stream);
    *string = realloc(*string, (counter+1) * sizeof(char));
    (*string)[counter++] = c;
} while(c != ENTER && !feof(stream));

(*string)[counter-1] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
char *p = malloc(1);
read(fopen("sam.txt", "r"), &p);
printf("%s\n", p);
return 0;
}
```

The contents of `sam.txt` were printed exactly.
I guess you were passing the `file name` instead of a `file pointer to the file`. Also you need to pass the reference of the pointer to apply realloc on `p`. Hope this helps.